# How to change navwalker's dropdown mark-up?

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [Bootstrap 4 Navwalker, bs4navwalker](https://github.com/dominicbusinaro/bs4navwalker), to step through my WordPress menu items and generate a navbar, like...

## Single level - works

```
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu([
      'menu'            => 'primary',
      'theme_location'  => 'primary',
      'container'       => 'nav',
      'container_class' => 'sidebar-nav',
      'menu_id'         => 'sidebarnav',
      'depth'           => 2,
      'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
      'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
    ]);
    ?>
```

This correctly generates a navbar like ...

[image]

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul id="sidebarnav" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-3 nav-item active">
            <a title="Home Page" target="_blank" href="http://sandbox.contexthq.com/" class="nav-link active" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="icon-speedometer"></i>Home Page
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4 nav-item">
            <a title="Example Page" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/" class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="ti-layout-grid2"></i>Example Page
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5 nav-item">
            <a title="Custom Page" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/custom/" class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="ti-palette"></i>Custom Page
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

## Multi-level - preferred

The problem happens when it comes to drop-down/sub-menu items...

My theme handles those like this...

[image]

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul id="sidebarnav">
      <li class="selected">
            <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="icon-speedometer"></i>
                <span class="hide-menu">
                    Dashboard <span class="badge badge-pill badge-cyan">4</span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
              <li><a href="index.html">Minimal</a></li>
              <li><a href="index2.html">Analytical</a></li>
              <li><a href="index3.html">Demographical</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="index4.html" class="active">Modern</a></li>
              <li><a href="index5.html">Cryptocurrency</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="ti-layout-grid2"></i>
                <span class="hide-menu">Apps</span>
          </a>
          <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
              <li><a href="app-calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a href="app-chat.html">Chat app</a></li>
              <li><a href="app-ticket.html">Support Ticket</a></li>
              <li><a href="app-contact.html">Contact / Employee</a></li>
              <li><a href="app-contact2.html">Contact Grid</a></li>
              <li><a href="app-contact-detail.html">Contact Detail</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="has-arrow">Inbox</a>
                  <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                      <li><a href="app-email.html">Mailbox</a></li>
                      <li><a href="app-email-detail.html">Mailbox Detail</a></li>
                      <li><a href="app-compose.html">Compose Mail</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </nav>
```

... That is, it:

- adds a `<span>` with `.hide-menu` inside the top-level link `<a>`
- adds an `<ul>` unordered list afterward.

This is the approach I want to stick to.

## Multi-level: what navwalker gives

However, when using the navwalker, I get...

[image]

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul id="sidebarnav" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-3 nav-item dropdown active">
            <a title="Home Page" target="_blank" href="http://sandbox.contexthq.com/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="icon-speedometer"></i>Home Page</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="http://sandbox.contexthq.com/sample-page/" class="dropdown-item" aria-expanded="false"><i class="ti-palette"></i>Sample Page</a>
                </div>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

That is, it...

- places a `<div>` with `.dropdown-menu` inside the `<a>`, instead of a `<span>` with `.hide-menu`
- for the sub-menu items, uses `<a>` elements

I'm sure this is standard Bootstrap 4 behaviour - in fact, I have happily used it this way on a different site. However, it's not what is needed by the Bootstrap 4 theme which I have purchased and am currently trying to turn in to a WordPress theme...

## The question

How can I use the bs4navwalker but in a way that will present drop-down/sub-menu items in a manner consistent with my theme... ?

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 add a script to header like below ( it's always better go for the enqueue method . i need some one to help me with properly adding the below script in WordPress way .jquery should run before the second script>

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });


  return false;
});
});

</script>
```

STEP 2 Add the css like below :

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

STEP 3 Now go inside the walker class : search for && `0 === $depth` and remove it. Also make sure that

```
'depth' => 3
```

Now it should start showing the 3rd level menu . some additional css might be required.
Just let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't thought of manipulating the page like that. But I was hopeful a solution would come from modifying the navwalker class, rather than this.